# Can't enable Docker Xdebug

Tags: docker, debian, xdebug

I am trying to use Xdebug on Docker, I'm using Debian, PHP 8. Cannot make a connection with Xdebug. Won't give any errors.

Since I don't get any errors or logs can't figure out what is wrong with my configurations.

Everything builds normally with the configurations below. Could someone help me activate Xdebug?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim as builder

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1

RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget gnupg2 unzip curl cron make \
    locales ca-certificates apt-transport-https default-mysql-client-core sendmail \
    default-jre-headless ca-certificates-java

RUN sed -i 's/mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt/!mozilla\/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt/g' /etc/ca-certificates.conf
RUN update-ca-certificates

RUN wget -q https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg -O- | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ stretch main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list && \
    cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d && \
    rm -rf ondrej-ubuntu*

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    zip \
    unzip \
    sudo \
    libzip-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libreadline-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    g++ \
    nano \
    vim \
    php-xdebug

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_current.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        php8.0 \
        php8.0-mysql \
        php8.0-gd \
        php8.0-xml \
        php8.0-mbstring \
        php8.0-curl \
        libapache2-mod-php8.0 \
        php8.0-intl \
        php8.0-soap \
        php8.0-zip \
        php8.0-ldap \
        php8.0-dev \
        php-pear \
        mysql-client \
        apache2 \
        php-xdebug && \
    update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0 && \
        a2enmod php8.0 && \
        a2enmod rewrite && \
        a2enmod ssl

RUN echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    echo "tr_TR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen

RUN apt-get -y autoremove wget unzip && apt-get -y clean && \
    rm -rf "/tmp/"* "/var/cache/apt" "/usr/share/man" "/usr/share/doc" "/usr/share/doc-base" "/usr/share/info/*" >> /dev/null

RUN chown -R www-data. /var/www/html

RUN apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get -y clean && \
    rm -rf "/tmp/"* "/var/cache/apt" "/usr/share/man" "/usr/share/doc" "/usr/share/doc-base" "/usr/share/info/*" >> /dev/null

RUN curl -Ss https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN a2enmod rewrite

CMD service apache2 restart

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]

EXPOSE 80
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.3"
networks:
  my_network:
volumes:
  my_volume:

services:
  mysqllatest:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqllatest
    volumes:
      - my_volume:/var/lib/mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    tty: true
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: local_db
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: toor
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor
      MYSQL_SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - my_network

  php8debian:
    container_name: php8debian
    build: ./base/
    volumes:
      - ../:/var/www/html/
      - ./server/php/vhost/000-default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
      - ./server/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
    ports:
      - 80:80
    extra_hosts:
      - "mysite.test:127.0.0.1"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - my_network
```

xdebug.ini

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so

[XDebug]

xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.client_host = 'host.docker.internal'
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "hostname": "0.0.0.0",
            "pathMappings": {
                "/var/www/html": "${workspaceRoot}/my_site"
            },
            "log": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Add `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10` to your `xdebug.ini`, and then check the output of `/tmp/xdebug.log` (in your container) to see what it says?
Which Xdebug version is actually being installed? What does `xdebug_info()` output say in a request that you're trying to debug?
Your set-up does look correct.

Comment: I added the configurations into the .ini file, but nothing was displayed.

Comment: @ersincebi 1) *" What does `xdebug_info()` output say in a request that you're trying to debug?"* Anything for that? Need to see the actual live config -- maybe the settings were not applied etc. 2) *"I added the configurations into the .ini file, but nothing was displayed."* Be specific please. Are you saying that the log file was not created or what? Make sure that such file is writeable by any user. Or have it in another place where Apache/PHP can write for sure. 3) You use Apache... Do you have SELinux by any chance active there?